# Count number of cells with a value in each row of a table

Tags: excel, count, powerquery

I wish to count the number of blank cells within each cell of a column using PQ.

e.g.

[image]

There appears to be a count blank function but this counts the number of blank cells vertically. I wish to count the number of blank cells horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add index column  (using default, that starts at zero)

Then add column ... custom column... with formula

```
= List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.ToList(Source{[Index]}), each if _=null then 1 else 0))
```

It converts the row into a record

Then converts the record into a list

Then transforms each item in the list to a 1 if null or 0 if not

Then takes the sum of that

Alternate:

```
= List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Source))-List.NonNullCount(Record.ToList(Source{[Index]}))
```

In all instances, replace **Source** with the name of your actual prior step

Comment: any idea why it doesn't appear to work with the above text showing in update? Worked in the example but here everything just returns back to 0.

Comment: you referred to Source. Your final step name is  #"Replaced Value"   use that instead